# Eclipse automatic build for custom projects

Tags: eclipse, build, headless

In Eclipse while creating the new Java Project (with our own custom wizards) I have associated a new builder to the project. Now the created java project has JavaNature and two builders associated with it.

1. org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder
2. com.company.project.custombuilder

The .project file contents looks like this.

```
<buildSpec>
<buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.ui.externaltools.ExternalToolBuilder</name>
        <triggers>full,incremental,</triggers>
        <arguments>
            <dictionary>
                <key>LaunchConfigHandle</key>
                <value>&lt;project&gt;/.externalToolBuilders/com.company.project.custombuilder.launch</value>
            </dictionary>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

I have to automate the building of this eclipse project.
If it is simple Java Project i can export the project as Ant Script and run the corresponding build.xml from ant.
Now my question is : 
What are the different possibilities to automate my custom builder? Any clues will greatly help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's the purpose of your custom builder? What does it have to do?

Comment: It will actually convert all my packages/applets into CAP files using JCDK (JavaCard Development Kit). I can do this by adding some more lines to build.xml file, but my requirement is already existing builder code i should reuse (i shouldn't break it).

Answer (score 1):

Builders are sort of hard to find in the Eclipse documentation, but the information is there. Below are some links. Essentially the builds are triggers by resource change notifications from the workspace.

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm?

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_core_resources_builders.html